# "ngCordovaOauth is not available" error for ionic app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I have a Ionic app on Android and i want to add an Facebook Login feature using [ngCordovaOauth](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/) plugin but i get:

```
0     851065   error    Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module 
starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCordovaOauth due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCordovaOauth' is not available! You either misspelled
the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify 
the dependencies as the second argument.
....
```

I try to load the plugin according to [here](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/blob/master/README.md). I used bower to load the plugin

```
bower install ng-cordova-oauth -S
```

Then I added the line to *index.html*

```
<script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
```

After that, i added the dependency to module *app.js*

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngMessages','ngCordova','ngCordovaOauth','ksSwiper','starter.services','starter.controllers'])
```

It gives the error when i added 'ngCordovaOauth'. I also try to download the *ng-cordova-oauth.min.js* file manually and add it to www/js folder and added

```
<script src="js/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
```

to the *index.html* file after i uninstall via bower. This also didn't work. I also try to remove the Android platform and add it again and didn't work.

I think i try everything that i can do but it seems doesn't work. It *should* find the ngCordovaOauth but it doesn't. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

index.html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; *; style-src  &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; *">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="lib/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/swiper/dist/js/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-swiper/dist/angular-swiper.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-messages.js"></script> 
<script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where did you try to include the script in your index.html file?

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: what version of ng-cordova do you have installed? v0.1.24-alpha is the version that fixed that OAuth dependency issue.

Comment: I checked the version which was 0.1.23. I updated to 0.1.24 but didn't solve my issue. Still i get the same error.

Comment: @gkocyigit make sure you delete and rebuild;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, although I did install ng-cordova-oauth correctly and I did not misspell its name.
My problem was that I blindly copied

```
<script src="../ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
```

from ng-cordova-oauth's README file into my `index.html`, whereas the path was wrong ! Indeed, the right path was the one you specified in your question : `lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js`!
So, to any person having the same issue, I would suggest checking their `ng-cordova-oauth.min.js`'s path in their `index.html`.